# Misleading Off-Topic-Default-Text

Tags: discussion

Today there was this question asked: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63820/noah-religion-and-darwinism The way I read it, it asks whether the bible is compatible with the idea of intelligent design proposed in the Noah-movie. It surely is off-topic and it was put on hold... with this reason:

> "Questions seeking **scientific solutions or explanations** are off-topic unless they relate directly to a cited work of fiction. There are a number of other Stack Exchange sites dedicated to answering questions on non-fictional sciences."

Now that surly is not the problem of that question. Shouldn't there be a more generic off-topic text to cover situations like that? Or should there be a second off-topic reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can already do custom text when voting to close a question as off-topic.

In the vote to close screen, under **off-topic**, there’s an option of **other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)**, and you can fill in custom text there. Here’s a screenshot:

[image]

When the next person votes to close, they’ll be shown that custom reason as an option alongside the default options. If a majority of close votes use that as their close reason, then that’s what gets displayed on the question.

(At least, I assume it would. I can’t find any examples right now.)

Comment: Or you could reference them to another stack with a link...